# how to create a server that send image from a request images from Glide?

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I'm using `Glide` as my image loader to client.
and I create my own server from java.

**My server's code:**

```
            File f = new File(imageLocation);
            try{
                bi = ImageIO.read(f);
            }catch (Exception e){
                f = new File(imageLocation);
                bi = ImageIO.read(f);
            }


            respond = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
            respond += "Date: " + LocalDateTime.now() + "\r\n";
            respond += "Content-Type: image/png\r\n";
            respond += "Content-Length: " + f.length() + "\r\n";
            respond += "Connection: keep-alive\r\n";
            respond += "\r\n";
            output.write((respond).getBytes());
            output.flush();
            ImageIO.write(bi,"JPG",output);
            output.flush();
```

I tested from my browser and it work fine,
but when I call using `Glide` from android, no image displayed

Comment: Did you try reading the response to see what it is saying? seems a little weird to have all this information be hardcoded. Perhaps do a little more search into the APIs you're using and validate what you're sending vs what you're receiving in both conditions.

Comment: Hi jox, yes i can see what Glide send to server and server can handle it, but i still trying to figure how to get any exception from Glide if exist. Do you have any suggestion another way to send a image in http way?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/glidelibrary/1UZskRTQ-gI/discussion

Answer (score 1):

The `Content-Length` may confuse glide, because you're lying about it, the original File length may not be the same as the re-encoded JPG output.

You're also lying about the `Content-Type` because it's a JPG, not a PNG as you state it, however I think Glide would ignore that.

I think it would be better to just send the `imageLocation`'s bytes to the `output`, then the `Content-Length` can be predicted simply.

> i still trying to figure how to get any exception from Glide if exist

As stated in the [Google Groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/glidelibrary/1UZskRTQ-gI/discussion), read https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Debugging-and-Error-Handling and I suggest you add `.listener(new RequestListener...)` before `.into(imageView)` and log the arguments to see what's going on.